# Is there a 'protected' analog in golang for accessing an embded structs private methods?

Tags: go

In Java/C++ you can use the 'protected' to make private methods/attributes of base classes accessible from inherited classes. I noticed in Go there doesn't seem to be anything similar.

If that's the case, what's the standard practice in Go for when you might want to access an embedded types private methods?

More specifically:

I have a package called package1, there's a method called setUpPackage1() to setup package1 -
(setUpPackage1() is intentionally unreported because package1 is never intended to be used as is, it's indented to be used as a base to be extended upon)

I then make a separate package package2 - which has a struct called package2 that has package1 embedded in it.

I want to create a method called NewPackage2(). I want to call package1.setUpPackage1() inside NewPackage2().

Is there any way Go will allow something like this, and if not, what's the Go way?

Comment: There's no notion of inheritance in go (only embedding), so "protected" doesn't make sense. You just can't access private methods (or private fields of structs) for types that aren't in your package. Without seeing specifically what you're trying to do, it's hard to answer the question, but a general (probably unhelpful) answer is that go is not java or c++ and you have to use a design approach that's suitable for the language. Can you flesh out your question with a specific design problem?

Comment: Hi @PaulHankin thanks for your reply. It's exactly what it sounds like, I have a struct that has a embedded struct and I want to access the private methods of the embedded struct for the outer structs constructor

Comment: @NimaKapoor There is no such thing as a contructor either. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and how to make a [mre]. Then edit your question to include some code showing what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @NimaKapoor I'm sorry, but there's no way to access unexported fields or methods of a struct outside of the package, and embedding the struct in another struct is no exception. That's why I suggested re-thinking your design

Comment: Note that "private" (which we call "unexported" in go) is not the same in go as in java or C++. An unexported function, field, method or type is available to anything within the same package, and unavailable to anything outside of that package. Related types which may need to peek inside each other's data or call each other's unexported methods tend to go in the same package, or at least that's the design ideal in go.

Answer (score 0):

Use unexported method.

In Go, a name is unexported if it begins with a lowercase letter, which means you can not access the unexported method from other packages ("private" to other packages). So keep the type with unexported method and code using it in the same package, you can still use the method inside. This effect is similar to "protected" in C++, IMHO.

Comment: The question is about embedding, though.

Answer (score -2):

A package is the smallest unit of private encapsulation in Go.

If you really need a bigger level of control, you can define a public SetupPackage1 and define the package 1 as *internal* to restrict access.

https://dave.cheney.net/2019/10/06/use-internal-packages-to-reduce-your-public-api-surface

Comment: Oh -1 I will cry…

Comment: This isn't such a bad question or answer. Looks like a lot of automated bots spamming SO with negative marking. Feel sorry for you.

Comment: you might want to improve that answer to better illusrate the solution you are proposing.